# How to access https site using android emulator

Tags: android

I am new to mobile application security testing.I am trying to access https site on android emulator. My configuration is as follows
Android platform 2.1
I can access http site like Google on emulator without any problem.But when i tried to access https site like facebook or any other. I can not access. Kindly let me know how to access secure sites on android emulator.

Comment: We need more details: Are you trying to access HTTPS sites from the stock Android browser or your own application with a WebView?

Comment: look at [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) , maybe help. table 2, network part.